# How to use true or false in json payload of python?

Tags: python, json

```
 def putApicall(self, versionId):
        url = 'https://' + testURL + '/api/apis/versions'
        payload = {
            "ProxyAPIList": {
                "ProductionEndpoint": [
                    {
                        "OAuth20Supported": "true",
                        "OAuthProvider": "Okta",
                        "OAuth10aSupported": false,
                        "ClientAuthPolicyOption": []
                    },
                    {
                        "OAuth20Supported": "true",
                        "OAuthProvider": "Azure",
                        "OAuth10aSupported": false,
                        "ClientAuthPolicyOption": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            "OperationsOAuthDetails": {
                "Operation": []
            },
            "APIVersionID": versionId
        }
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        result = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, cookies=cookie)
```

I am getting an error saying it is unable to detect 'false' which is boolean. can someone please help on how to use this payload effectively?

Comment: It should be `False`.

Comment: with a capital `F`

Comment: `payload` is python, not json, so you have to use the python `False` instead of the json `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format](https://json.org). It may look a lot like Javascript or Python, but really its a serialized representation of data using the UTF-8 character encoding standard. JSON can be loaded into or dumped from program language specific data structures, but once in the language, that language's syntax and semantics prevail.

JSON booleans are `true` and `false` but they must be translated to Python boolean objects represented by the Python keywords `True` and `False`.

In your case, you are using `"true"` - which is a string, not the JSON `true`, and `false` which to Python is just a regular variable name that can be bound to anything (or nothing, raising an error). I don't know whether your API demands strings `"true"` and `"false"` or JSON booleans. Assuming booleans, your data should look like:

```
    payload = {
        "ProxyAPIList": {
            "ProductionEndpoint": [
                {
                    "OAuth20Supported": True,
                    "OAuthProvider": "Okta",
                    "OAuth10aSupported": False,
                    "ClientAuthPolicyOption": []
                },
                {
                    "OAuth20Supported": True,
                    "OAuthProvider": "Azure",
                    "OAuth10aSupported": False,
                    "ClientAuthPolicyOption": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "OperationsOAuthDetails": {
            "Operation": []
        },
        "APIVersionID": versionId
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation. That clears my doubt